# Sorting hierarchical data by property when using apoc.convert.toTree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

New to Neo4j and I've tried various approaches with both Cypher and APOC based on similar questions asked on here but no luck since none are sort-tree combos. Let's say I have some hierarchical data that is just a bunch of root nodes with children and all nodes have the property 'name'. As of right now (with query below), when displaying the result by name, my data resembles:

```
zxcv
  rtyu
asdf
  qwer
    wert
  bbbb
    fghj
    yuio
```

What can I add to the following query that will sort by name such that the entire tree is sorted?

```
MATCH p=(n:Code)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(n)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value
```

If I tack on `SORT BY value.name` it only sorts the root nodes since that is what is at the top of what is returned. Can't figure out how/where to sort the nodes before collecting, or when I did then I couldn't figure out how to make the collection afterward. Happy to use `apoc.coll.sortNodes`, `apoc.coll.sort`, etc., but can't quite figure out how to work them in.

**Update**

This gets a little closer but still only sorting the root

```
MATCH (n:Code)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(n)
WITH n
ORDER BY n.name
MATCH p=(n:Code)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(n)
WITH COLLECT (p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (n:Code)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(m)
WHERE NOT (m)-[:HAS_CHILD]->()
WITH n, m
ORDER BY n.name, m.name
MATCH p=(n:Code)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(m)
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(n)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value
```